# How does listSelector of ListView work?

Tags: android, listview

Romain Guy himself states that `TouchMode` does not have any `selection` or `focus` in [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/8IpYFn26qMg). I used `android:listSelector="?android:colorPressedHighlight"` for a `listview` and the items I touched retained a blue background. How does this work if `TouchMode` doesn't have `selection`?

If listSelector is not the prescribed way to show selected items in touch, how exactly is it done in the youtube app (the red bg in the attached image).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

listSelector on ListViews are for phones with bezels/D-pads or GoogleTVs with D-pads

[image]

Notice that once you touch them, they remain highlighted. That's because the touch event is mapped to a click event and the selection stays highlighted because that's the only way to keep track of what you've selected (assuming your screen is not touch enabled and for instance you're only controlling the device from the Directional Pad of your remote control).

[image]

Comment: The last four lines don't make any sense to me!! Can you explain in simpler words? Also please have a look at my edit

Comment: The YouTube example doesn't follow the Android TouchMode conventions of selectors. If it did, you would touch it, and then it would change the highlight of the button, and then the highlight would disappear as soon as your finger lifted itself from it. The UI of YouTube seems perfectly familiar to you, but it's only familiar because most of the List UIs we're familiar with were built initially on top of non-touch PCs and non-touch ATMs. Android made a point of getting rid of that UI convention for its touch devices (but ListView still utilizes that convention for backward compatibility).

Comment: After all, there are still Android phones that are being made without a touch screen (mostly for the Chinese Market). The D-pad interface is still very important for accessibility reasons for disabled people. Most Android/Google TVs do not have touch screens (yet). And applications like YouTube have started to blur the line between being run on Android phones and run on Televisions (so sometimes, it has a good touch screen and sometimes it doesn't).